# Faster technologies compared to Impala in Hadoop stack?

Tags: hadoop, impala

Have been using Impala for over 4 months and we have found it to be very fast compared to hive in most cases. Since we are in a process of assessing fast frameworks in Hadoop for data processing wanted to know if their are any more frame works in the native Hadoop environment which are faster than impala.(Can be any type, In-memory or MR1 or yarn based!) A comprehensive list would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala is a good choice in terms of speed. For standard Map/Reduce environments you will not likely find a better one: impala is able to cache data blocks and is well faster than M/R even for reading uncached blocks off disk.  But of course given that you have several months of experience with impala - you already knew that.  AFAIK there is not another near real time hive access mechanism using the native hadoop structures.